# Can a CentOS 8 chrony client synchronize with a CentOS 7 ntp server?

Tags: centos7, ntp, chrony, centos8

Can a CentOS 8 chrony client synchronize with a CentOS 7 ntp server? By ntp server, I mean it was configured through yum installing the ntp package and not the chrony package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Both of those implement the NTP protocol.